# I am trying to work out Minutes Per Goal using data from a data frame and the rows are printing wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make this dataframe that works out the Minutes Per Goal of three players, I have the Mins played column and the Goals column and I am trying to create a third column which works out the Minutes Per Goal. However, when I look at the database the columns for MinsPerGoal has been insertly weird.

```
MANU = dframe.loc[dframe['Team']== 'Man Utd',['Player','Mins played','Goals']].set_index('Player')
for row in range(len(MANU)):

    MinsPlayed = MANU['Mins played'][row]
    Goals = MANU['Goals'][row] 
    MinPerGoal = MinsPlayed/Goals
    MANU['MinPerGoal'[row]] = MinPerGoal
```

And its doing this

```
Mins played Goals   M   i   n
Player                  
Romelu Lukaku   2819    16  313.222222  253.777778  162.777778
Alexis Sanchez  2284    9   313.222222  253.777778  162.777778
Anthony Martial 1465    9   313.222222  253.777778  162.777778



313.222222  253.777778  162.777778
313.222222  253.777778  162.777778
313.222222  253.777778  162.777778
```

It's printing three columns instead of one

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting too detailed.  You computed the series of GPM, and then assigned the *entire series* to *every* row of the df.

Instead, just do the whole computation in series form:

```
MANU['MinPerGoal'] = MANU['Mins played'] / MANU['Goals']
```

No `for` loop, no three-line, detailed computation.  just tell PANDAS that you want a new column derived as the quotient of the corresponding values in two other columns.